# [go-gorm]how to update one more column when I use the soft-delete method

Tags: go-gorm

When using the soft-delete, gorm can only update one column like deleted_at or flag.

But now, I alse need to update the `deleted_by` column.

I want to record the delete operater.

How can I do this?

I dont want to update the column by myself like this. I want to learn more official ways.

```golang
AdminDB(ctx, a.DB).Where("id=?", id).UpdateColumns(map[string]interface{}{
  "deleted_by": 168,
})
```